# Передвижение шарика по picturebox в c#

Tags: c#, графика, разработка-игр

Пишу игру "Лабиринт" на c#, сам лабиринт отрисовывается на picturebox. Осталось сделать так. чтоб пользователь "мог играть". В общем, как организовать передвижение шарика по picturebox в с#?

Comment: Пиши не на PictureBox, а на событии Paint окна, в крайнем случае создай свой UserControl. А также посмотри в сторону IsDoubleBuffered и SetStyle(,). Тогда поймешь, что за штука у тебя будет, и изучай свойства и события

Answer (score 1):

Используйте событие KeyDown формы которое включает таймер который в зависимости от нажатой кнопки перерисовывает картинку так как нужно. Затем в событии KeyUp отключайте таймер. Получится что пока пользователь держит кнопку картинка движется в нужную сторону.

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать так, чтоб картинка не выходила за границы стен лабиринта? То есть, если на пути стена, то туда нельзя идти

Comment: Вот здесь есть подробное описание
http://noregret.org/tutor/n/collision/
Вкратце если обе проекции стены вашего лабиринта пересекаются с проекциями картинки то значит произошло столкновение